# get averages using mongodb aggregation from array containing objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a problem getting the scores from all students who answered questions in a test using the mongodb aggregation pipeline approach

My aggregation pipeline gives an array of objects , which is made up of every students answer to the test questions.

The pipeline would be something like the one below, my example is simplified from my actual problem. Basically I group and push each questions array for each user into scores field. Then I use reduce to flatten the scores field

```
{ $group: { 
    _id: {}, 
    scores: { $push: "$questions" }
} }, 
{ $addFields: { 
    testScores: {
        $reduce: {
            input: "$scores",
            initialValue: [ ],
            in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
        }
    } 
} }
```

The result would look something like:

```
testScores: [
    { id: 'questionOne' score: 1 }, 
    { id: 'questionOne', score: 3 }, 
    { id: 'questionOne', score: 8 }, 
    { id: 'questionOne' score: 2 },
    ....
    { id: 'questionFifty' score: 1 }, 
    { id: 'questionFifty', score: 3 }, 
    { id: 'questionFifty', score: 8 }, 
    { id: 'questionFifty' score: 2 }
]
```

My question is how do I get the average score for all scores for 'questionOne' and all the other questions ?
I cannot unwind my array as I have a large number of tests and it seems mongoDb cannot unwind a sufficient number without returning null for the aggregation result.

In JavaScript I'd use reduce but as I understand it, mongodb allows use of vars outside the reduce function but as far as I understand you cannot modify the reduce function so something similar to the function below would not be possible.

```
myArray.reduce((acc, next){
    if(acc[next.id]}{
       acc[next.id].score += next.score
       acc[next.id].count+= 1
       acc[next].avg = acc[next.id].score/acc[next.id].count
    }else{
        acc[next.id].score = next.score
        acc[next.id].count = 1
    }
 return acc
},{} }
```

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: The pipeline would be something like the one below, my example is simplified from my actual problem.
Basically I group and push each questions array for each user into scores field. 
Then I use reduce to flatten the scores field

{$group:{
     _id: {},
    scores:{$push:"$questions)
}},
{$addFields:{
    testScores:{$reduce: {input: "$scores",initialValue: [ ],in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }}}
}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's possible with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) but there are two important caveats:

- inside [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) when you define `vars` section you can only refer to variables defined in outer scopes but you can't define multiple variables and refer to each other in the same block - that's why there has to be a lot of nestings in this solution
- `$reduce` exposes `$$value` variable which represents current state of the aggregation. The thing is that you should consider that variable as **immutable** which means you can refer to it but you can't modify it

Then you can try following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            averages: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$testScores",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                index: { $indexOfArray: [ "$$value.id", "$$this.id" ] }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $let: {
                                    vars: { 
                                        prev: { 
                                            $cond: [ { $ne: [ "$$index", -1 ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$value", "$$index" ] }, { id: "$$this.id", score: 0, count: 0 } ] 
                                        } 
                                    },
                                    in: {
                                        $let: {
                                            vars: {
                                                updated: {
                                                    id: "$$prev.id",
                                                    score: { $add: [ "$$prev.score", "$$this.score" ] },
                                                    count: { $add: [ "$$prev.count", 1 ] },
                                                    avg: {
                                                        $divide: [ { $add: [ "$$prev.score", "$$this.score" ] }, { $add: [ "$$prev.count", 1 ] } ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            in: {
                                                $cond: {
                                                    if: { $eq: [ "$$index", -1 ] },
                                                    then: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$updated" ] ] },
                                                    else: { $concatArrays: [ { $slice: [ "$$value", "$$index"] }, [ "$$updated" ], { $slice: [ "$$value", { $add: [ "$$index", 1 ] }, { $size: "$$value" }] } ] }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Actually each `$let` defines a step of algorithm here:

- using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to check if there's an aggregate for currently processed document
- using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) and [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get previous value for currently processed `id` or provide default value
- then under `updated` we calculate new values including `average`

to return the value we should consider two cases:

- when there's no previous value then we simply append `updated` document to current array (using [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html))
- when we have to "update" exisiting aggregate we have to remove the old value and add the new one - [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/index.html) can be used here to get the documents before and after current `$$index`

For your example it outputs:

```
{
    "averages" : [
            {
                    "id" : "questionOne",
                    "score" : 14,
                    "count" : 4,
                    "avg" : 3.5
            },
            {
                    "id" : "questionFifty",
                    "score" : 14,
                    "count" : 4,
                    "avg" : 3.5
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out

Comment: Miki, I take my hat off to you , the nesting alone fried my brain as does the repetition if you have to do this for several collections of data , it appears very cumbersome compared to a javascript solution , but I am very new to this and much more familiar with JS. I tried your solution out but got an error 'A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.'  With my limited experience I did not resolve this. I finally did a part aggregation pipeline ( to pull out averages and arrays of scores) and node solution (to easily reduce arrays, get quartile values etc).